# How do I get text appear on the right side of the map when I click on a country using Javascript events?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the task:

*Create a web page showing the map of Scandinavia on the left and a blank  element on the right. Here it is a good idea to use the map as a background image in an element.
Add round - elements (Hint: border-radius) with each of the four flags and place them over the country to which they belong (Hint: position).
Add an effect when you hover the mouse pointer over a flag.
For example, you can change the arrow to a hand, and you can do something with the  elements that make it clear that you are holding them over.
Add a click event to each of the flags. When a flag is clicked, a text about the country should appear in the  element on the right. The text must contain information about the country, and must at least contain area, population, currency and capital.*

All I have left is to get the text about the the clicked country to appear on the right side of the map.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        *,*::before,*::after{
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .container{
            display: flex;
        }
        
        .container>div:first-child{
            position: relative;
            height: 500px;
            width:500px;
            padding:1rem;
            background-color: #eee;
            background-image:url(./Oppgave2/Skandinavia.png);
            background-position: center;
            background-size:contain;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }
        .container>div:first-child .flag{
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
            position:absolute;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding:0.1rem;
        }
        .container>div:first-child img{
            width: 28px;
            height: 28px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            
        }

        .container>div:first-child img:hover{
            cursor:pointer;
            transform:scale(1.2);
        }
        .norway{
            top: 300px;
            left: 126px;
        } 

        .finland{
            top:234px;
            left: 350px;
        }

        .sweden{
            top:282px;
            left: 203px;
        }

        .denmark{
            top:447px;
            left: 120px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <div class="flag norway" >
                <img src="./Oppgave2/Norge.png" alt="Norway">
            </div>
            <div class="flag denmark">
                 <img src="./Oppgave2/Danmark.png" alt="Denmark">
            </div>
           
            <div class="flag sweden"> 
                <img src="./Oppgave2/Sverige.png"  alt="Sweden">
            </div>

           <div class="flag finland">
               <img src="./Oppgave2/Finland.png" alt="Finland">
           </div>
            
        </div>
        <div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

All I have left is to get the text about the country I want to click to appear on the right side of the map when I click the country. So if I want to click on Norway, it should appear a text containing information about Norway on the right side of the map. The same goes for Sweden, Denmark and Finland's flags.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :focus pseudo to display details after click event. Also, you have to add tabindex attribute to elements you want to be clicked.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by that, and could you also possibly write it in the code, so I can understand where to add it?